# How I can handle background notification on flutter IOS?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I'm trying to save received notification in SQLite
Notification is showing up with ios
But i can't handle it in my code to save it,although there is a function for background handler
Is there any solution for this issue ?

Comment: Can you share the background handler function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.